# Why does the cursor go to the last TextBox when I run app in visual c++ studio 2010 ?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I have several textboxes in my app. When I run it , the cursor goes to the last. How to make it go to first text box ? Or let that textboxes free , till I will click on one of them. Thanks! p.s. I can not share the photo here, because I must have at least 10 reputation for that . So I will share the link of photo in facebook
https://fbcdn-sphotos-c-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-prn1/t1/1451940_1420623288178236_2126027375_n.jpg

Comment: You need to set the tab order of your form/dialog. I have not developed with MFC in 5+ years so I can not tell you how to do that in Visual Studio 2010.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/csz6b8x8%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix this you need to set the tab order in your form or dialog.

[MSDN Link explaining how to change the tab order in Visual Studio 2010](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/csz6b8x8%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)